# NodeJS: async result order

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

my goal is
1. extract unique data
2. counting each data

```
async.waterfall([function(callback){
    var q = mongoose.model('student').distinct('hobby');
    q.exec(function(err,rst){
        callback(null,rst);
    });
},
function(arg1,callback){
    var temp = new Array();
    async.map(arg1,function(val,callback1){
        var qq = mongoose.model('student').where('hobby').equals(val).count();
        qq.exec(function(err,rst){
            temp.push(rst);
        });
        callback1();
    },function(e,r){});
    callback(null,temp);
}], function(err,result){console.log("result:"+result);});
```

Problems occurred when counting each data..

It's not the same order as the original array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple issues in the code.  The callbacks are not in correct places.  In addition, async.mapSeries() should be used instead of async.map() to keep the array in original order.  Here is the revised code:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    var q = mongoose.model('student').distinct('hobby');
    q.exec(function(err,rst){
      callback(null,rst); 
    });
  },
  function(arg1,callback){
    var temp = new Array();
    async.mapSeries(arg1,function(val,callback1){
      var qq = mongoose.model('student').where('hobby').equals(val).count();
      qq.exec(function(err,rst){
        temp.push(rst);
        callback1();  // call here instead of outside
      });
    },function(e,r){
      callback(null,temp);  // call here instead of outside
    });
  }
], function(err,result){
  console.log("result:"+result);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Ben! You really saved my day :)